# What would the original C code of an assembler instruction loading a (half)word from an array of chars have looked like?

Tags: c, mips, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I'm decompiling an old video game.

Originally written in 68000 assembly, it was rewritten in C to port it to the PC in 1995. This version was then ported to the Sony PlayStation 2, and somehow the debug information made it to retail. Because of this, I have not only the function names, but also the function signatures, the names and types of global and local variables, and struct and union declarations.

Reading the MIPS assembly, I've noticed several times that an instruction loads a word or a halfword from a struct member, actfree, that I know to be an array of chars.

Example:

```
lw  a0,16(sp)
lh  a1,58(v0)
```

This loads the struct from the stack, then loads a halfword, meaning two bytes, from offset 58, which corresponds to member array actfree, index 12. This member is declared as:

```
unsigned char actfree[22]
```

In this case, it is used as the second argument for a function that accepts a short as its second argument.

In at least one other instance, a full word, meaning 4 bytes, was loaded from another index of array actfree.

The question is, what would the original C code getting a short or int from an array of chars have looked like?

It is not possible to pass in part of an array in C, so the closest I've got for passing in two chars from the array as a short is:

```
myFunction(myStruct->actfree[12] | (myStruct->actfree[13] << 8));
```

And for comparisons, in this example for four loaded chars, I'd just have to duplicate the test for each index:

```
if (char1 != 0 && char2 != 0 && char3 != 0 && char4 != 0)
```

I'm not a C wizard, though. Anyone got a better idea?

Comment: There might not have been any C code to begin with? Assembly were quite common for game-programming 20 or so years ago.

Comment: it could be `((int*)myStruct->actfree)[6]`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think it's fair to treat this as "What would the equivalent C code look like".

Comment: Who said it was an array of chars? A struct would also be possible.

Comment: @ikegami If it's used for multiple purposes, it sounds like the analogy would be a `union`.

Comment: @Barmar, Fetching a field from a sequence of bytes is literally a struct member read. No arrays or unions needed.

Comment: @ikegami But they said that this field is used more generically. This use of 2 bytes is just one of the way it's used.

Comment: Sometimes it loads a word, sometimes a halfword. That sounds like `union {short s; int i}`

Comment: @Barmar, Re "*But they said that this field is used more generically.*", Pray tell what you think that means that doesn't apply to struct. `memmove`? Can use that on structs. You're making the same error as the OP and presuming an array when it could simply be a struct. /// There's no problems with a struct having both words and half-words

Comment: What is this `myFunction` doing with the short word? What is this `myFunction` really named? Does the name of the function give a hint about its purpose and what it might use the word for? What is the assembly code really doing? Both the function and the code calling the function? Without any kind of context it's really impossible to do anything but guess *badly*.

Comment: @ikegami My interpretation of the question is that it's reading the halfword and fullword from the same address. So they're not separate struct members, they're the same member being used in different ways.

Comment: @Barmar It just says they're being read from `actfree`, not from the same address within

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You mean 30 years ago. 20 years ago game programmers already using C++

What myFunction does it irrelevant. I know for sure that the assembly is loading from an array of chars, and that the function accepts a short.

Comment: @ikegami I'm not presuming anything. Like I said, I have the debug information. I know for a fact that it's an array of chars.

Comment: @IłyaBursov Yes, that does look like a good candidate! I just tried it, and it does work as expected!

Comment: @ikegami They've now edited the question to make it clear it's different offsets in the array, so I've deleted my union answer.

Comment: It may have been an array of characters, but it sounds like they're using it like a struct.

Comment: @Barmar I can't discount the possibility that the same offset is used in another place to load more bytes.

Comment: @user16316067 In that case, that struct member is being used like a union. If you want to understand what the code is doing, not just decompile to the original C, it's best to think in terms of higher-level concepts, not bytes.

Comment: @IłyaBursov If you can enter your solution as an answer, I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In C, this would be done using a struct rather than an array.

In the program below,

```c
s.w
```

becomes

```
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-48]
```

so basically something like

```
lw  a0,16(sp)
```

And

```c
s.h
```

becomes

```
movzx   eax, WORD PTR [rbp-6]
```

so basically something like

```
lh  a1,58(v0)
```

That's on an x86-64, but a compiler for the MIPS could do the same.

Program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct S {
   char a[16];
   uint32_t w;
   char b[38];
   uint16_t h;
};

void fh( uint16_t h ) { }

void fw( uint16_t w ) { }

int main( void ) {
   struct S s = { 0 };

   fh( s.w );  // mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-48]
   fh( s.h );  // movzx   eax, WORD PTR [rbp-6]
}
```

Comment: It is most definitely not a struct. The debug information includes all struct declarations, and it shows that at that offset there is an array of chars.

Comment: @user16316067 You asked what the C code would look like. This is equivalent.

Comment: @Barmar I asked what the C code would look like using the given data structure. This answer assumes that the assembly wasn't accessing an array, but a struct.

Comment: I think you're missing the point -- it's using the array as if it were a struct. Reading the first 2 elements of the array is equivalent to reading a `short` at the beginning of a struct.

Comment: They would generate the same assembly code @user16316067

Comment: Re "*This answer assumes that the assembly wasn't accessing an array, but a struct.*", Not quite. You asked how this would be done in C, and this answer says this would be done using a struct. I clearly showed that accessing a struct looks exactly like accessing an array. The only difference is that all the members of an array are the same size, but the members of a struct can vary in size. I've clarified this. There are other ways this can be done in C --you could even use inline assembly-- but I provided the simple normal way.

Comment: @ikegami Like I said in the same comment you quoted, I asked what the C code would look like using the given data structure, which is an array. I know that the way the assembly accesses struct members is similar, but it's not the same in C. Pointing at an index of the array will give me one char, not two.

Comment: Re "*I asked what the C code would look like using the given data structure, which is an array.*", And that's what I answered. I didn't change the structure of the data at all. What I showed works with your existing data. You keep bringing up the declared type of the data structure, but that it doesn't matter how it was declared where you saw it declared. I showed you how it would be done in C for the given data structure, as you asked.